# jQuery.getScript working on local but not on GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, github-pages, p5.js

I'm building a website with Jekyll. A lot of people will contribute on different javascript sketches that will be displayed on the home page randomly: some of them will be written with P5.js, other with other libraries.

Since I didn't want to load all the libraries on page load I generate a JSON with one object per script:

```
[
   {
      "title":"Title to display",
      "author":"Author",
      "description":"javascript, Processing",
      "kind":"javascript",
      "href":"link to the js hosted on GitHub Pages",
      "includes":[
         "link to external library hosted on CDN",
         "link to external library hosted on CDN"
      ]
   }
]
```

Then, using jQuery, I'm loading everything with this script:

```
var loadedData;

$(function() {
    // Load all the scripts in an array
    $.getJSON("{{ site.url }}/homepage.json", function(data) {
      loadedData = data;
      randomPost();
    });

    $("#jsRefresh").click(function() {
      $("canvas").remove();
      randomPost();
    });
});

function randomPost() {

  $("#loading").show();

  item = loadedData[Math.floor(Math.random() * loadedData.length)];

  var defer = $.Deferred();

  $.each(item.includes, function(index, value){
    defer.then(function() {
      $.getScript(value)
    });
  });

  defer.then(function() {
    $.getScript(item.href)
  });

  defer.resolve();

  $.when(defer).done(function() {
    $("#loading").hide();
    $(".item-title").html(item.title + ' | ' + item.author);
    $(".item-description").html(item.description);
  })
}
```

This code is working on my local server but when I upload it on GitHub Pages it doesn't load properly on page load.

If I click the refresh link that fires *randomPost()* again it loads the previous script.

The live example is currently hosted [here](https://codiceinutile.github.io/website-dev/)

Comment: where is getScript() ???

Answer (score 0):

Your whole $.when is only using one promise and you resolve it immediately , not based on any of the getScript completing. Since you resolve it immediately it is virtually the same as using no promise at all.

Also note that `$.getScript` is a `$.ajax` shortcut and `$.ajax` itself returns a promise

The norm for something like this would be to make an array of promises and `$.when` would not resolve until the array of promises all resolve

Something like:

```
 // library script promises
 var requests = item.includes.map(function(value) {
   return $.getScript(value)
 });
 // `$.when` doesn't accept array in jQuery versions <3
 $.when.apply(null, requests).then(function() {
   //want this to only load after include requests have loaded
   var mainScriptPromise =  $.getScript(item.href);           
    // return it to the next then() 
    return mainScriptPromise;
 }).then(function() {
   // fires after the main script promise resolves
   $("#loading").hide();
   $(".item-title").html(item.title + ' | ' + item.author);
   $(".item-description").html(item.description);
 });
```

Note that you will also need to add your own error handling if any of the promises don't resolve

[Demo using `$.get`](http://plnkr.co/edit/PU7rlmT1jWuIC1eeZGrL?p=preview)

Note you might want to look into using a load manager like Require.js

Comment: I implemented your code on my page but, still, the p5js scripts aren't loaded when I open the page for the first time and when I click on the refresh button are one step behind.

For example:
When I load the page item.title is "Should display squares" but the canvas doesn't show anything. If I click the refresh link the item.title is "Should display circles" but squares are loaded on the canvas.

Comment: Hard to help without a sandbox demo that can be forked and can use browser dev tools on.

Comment: the code is available on [GitHub here](https://github.com/codiceinutile/website-dev) and the compiled version is [here](https://codiceinutile.github.io/website-dev/)

Comment: Not interested in downloading a repo. The norm here is to use sandbox sites like plunker, jsfiddle, codepen etc where all have code access with no setup involved as well as simple ways to link to updates. Also allows scaling down to [mcve] without all the extra irrelevant noise

Comment: I'm sorry. This is my first question on Stackoveflow. I ported the script on [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fedpep/uf3ve3nc/)

Comment: Not familar with p5.js but both the fiddle and your github page throw same error `t is undefined` from the p5.js. Not sure what causes that one but it is probably easy to search

Comment: Since I'm loading the p5 libraries from a CDN, unfortunately I can't edit the files. Anyway I think this is a minor issues because - although not as expected - the scripts are loaded and attached to the DOM.